# Psycopg / Postgres : Connections hang out randomly

Tags: python, postgresql, cherrypy, psycopg2

I'm using psycopg2 for the cherrypy app I'm currently working on and cli & phpgadmin to handle some operations manually. Here's the python code :

```
#One connection per thread
cherrypy.thread_data.pgconn = psycopg2.connect("...") 
...
#Later, an object is created by a thread :
class dbobj(object):
 def __init__(self):
  self.connection=cherrypy.thread_data.pgconn
  self.curs=self.connection.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.DictCursor)
...
#Then,
try:
 blabla
 self.curs.execute(...)
 self.connection.commit()
except:
 self.connection.rollback()
 lalala
...
#Finally, the destructor is called :
def __del__(self):
 self.curs.close()
```

I'm having a problem with either psycopg or postgres (altough I think the latter is more likely). After having sent a few queries, my connections drop dead. Similarly, phpgadmin -usually- gets dropped as well ; it prompts me to reconnect after having made requests several times. Only the CLI remains persistent.

The problem is, these happen very randomly and I can't even track down what the cause is. I can either get locked down after a few page requests or never really encounter anything after having requested hundreds of pages. The only error I've found in postgres log, after terminating the app is :

```
...
LOG:  unexpected EOF on client connection
LOG:  could not send data to client: Broken pipe
LOG:  unexpected EOF on client connection
...
```

I thought of creating a new connection every time a new dbobj instance is created but I **absolutely** don't want to do this.

Also, I've read that one may run into similar problems unless all transactions are committed : I use the try/except block for every single INSERT/UPDATE query, but I never use it for SELECT queries nor do I want to write even more boilerplate code (btw, do they need to be committed ?). Even if that's the case, why would phpgadmin close down ?

max_connections is set to 100 in the .conf file, so I don't think that's the reason either. A single cherrypy worker has only 10 threads.

Does anyone have an idea where I should look first ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though I don't have any idea why successful `SELECT` queries block the connection, spilling `.commit()` after pretty much every single query that doesn't have to work in conjunction with another solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Psycopg2 needs a commit or rollback after every transaction, including SELECT queries, or it leaves the connections "IDLE IN TRANSACTION".  This is now a warning in the docs:

> Warning: By default, any query execution, including a simple SELECT will start a transaction: for long-running programs, if no further action is taken, the session will remain “idle in transaction”, an undesirable condition for several reasons (locks are held by the session, tables bloat...). For long lived scripts, either ensure to terminate a transaction as soon as possible or use an autocommit connection.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit difficult to see exactly where you're populating and accessing `cherrypy.thread_data`. I'd recommend investigating `psycopg2.pool.ThreadedConnectionPool` instead of trying to bind one conn to each thread yourself.