# How do I properly use psycopg2 with cherrypy?

Tags: python, thread-safety, psycopg2, cherrypy

I wrote a CherryPy webapp the other day. Some data is queried from PostgreSQL and I use psycopg2 for that. While everything worked alright in my local testing, it sometimes falls apart in real conditions (much more pageloads).

Unfortunately, I do not have the exact traceback messages right now but they were about not being able to connect or a connection being closed already if I recall correctly. I will add them as soon as I can.

[Psycopg / Postgres : Connections hang out randomly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173168/psycopg-postgres-connections-hang-out-randomly) seems to have a very similar problem but their solution seems like a hack. Another comment on that suggests using `psycopg2.pool.ThreadedConnectionPool`.

My relevant code snippets would be:

```
def connect_database(thread_index):
    cherrypy.thread_data.dbconn = psycopg2.connect(mydbstring)
    cherrypy.thread_data.dbconn.autocommit=True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cherrypy.engine.subscribe('start_thread', connect_database)
    cherrypy.quickstart(Root())
    cherrypy.engine.start()
    cherrypy.engine.block()
```

I use the database connection(s) like this:

```
with cherrypy.thread_data.dbconn.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM posts;")
    results = cursor.fetchall()
```

I got this far by reading through the (very random) http://tools.cherrypy.org/wiki/Databases . The comments on that page are almost 10 years old and seem very complicated. There must be a better way?(tm)

I assume that using `psycopg2.pool.ThreadedConnectionPool` would be the best way. How can I do that?

Comment: You may want to use SQLAlchemy. Here's an example of cherrypy tool for it: https://bitbucket.org/webknjaz/blueberrypy-wk/src/cb2753de29c4ec0f1be00baf2e828b35e0939b47/src/blueberrypy/tools.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#tools.py-102:155

Comment: I would really like to avoid dependencies. For now I reconnect to the database on every single request.