# How to rollback a postgresql connection when using cherrypy

Tags: postgresql, psycopg2, cherrypy, rollback

I use cherrypy to run an api and use thread_data to attach a postgresql cursor to each thread.

```
def connect_pg(thread_index):
    cherrypy.thread_data.pgdb = connect(**cherrypy.config['pgargs'])    
    dict_cur = cherrypy.thread_data.pgdb.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.DictCursor)
    dict_cur.close()
```

I then create a cursor using

`cherrypy.thread_data.pgdb.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.DictCursor)`

Occasionally a bad request may be made, which results in the error message

> InternalError: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block

The standard solution for this is to do a rollback (http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/faq.html).

However, rollback is a connection method and not a cursor method.

What are some good ways to deal with this error when using cherrpy's thread_data?

Comment: I think you want to create a CherryPy Tool for this. You may also want to use SQLAlchemy ORM. Here's an example of SQLAlchemy Cherrypy Tool: https://github.com/open-craft-guild/blueberrypy/blob/75ccae2/src/blueberrypy/tools.py#L102-L155

Answer (score 0):

I used autocommit within cherrypy and that has done the job nicely ([How do I properly use psycopg2 with cherrypy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37365358/how-do-i-properly-use-psycopg2-with-cherrypy)). I now create the cursor as follows:

```
def connect_pg(thread_index):
   cherrypy.thread_data.pgdb = connect(**cherrypy.config['pgargs'])   
   cherrypy.thread_data.pgdb.autocommit=True
   dict_cur = cherrypy.thread_data.pgdb.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.DictCursor)
   dict_cur.close()
```